# How do I set up a project for gcloud datastore emulator?

Tags: emulation, gcloud, datastore

I'm trying to do some offline development with gcloud sdk where I want to build a Python Flask app presenting data queried from a datastore. The reason for doing it offline is simply that it's faster during development, it will be deployed online later using App Engine.

First of all: The datastore emulator is running.

However I am having trouble importing data into the datastore. I am using below from [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/emulator-export-import) to try and import (with my values).

```
curl -X POST localhost:8081/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]:import \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"input_url":"[ENTITY_EXPORT_FILES]"}'
```

The problem I am having is that it just returns

`NOT FOUND`

I think I know what it is but not how to solve it: I don't have a project defined in my offline environment. So I wonder, how do I set up a project in my "offline cloud SDK environment"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PROJECT_ID for the DataStore Emulator is set during it's installation.

I've looked a bit into it and in the link at the bottom you can see how it's done. You need to set your project-id as an environment variable, or do it with an automatic command that sets it for you.

Have a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#automatically_setting_the_variables), I think this is what you're missing.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Hey again Nelumbo, I think that the NOT FOUND you received before and the NotFoundHandler are the same error. The common errors in [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/errors#NOT_FOUND) reflect that NOT_FOUND is generated when an request attempts to update an entity that does not exist which means that it might be a malformed address.

Taking into account that your Datastore emulator starts correctly, that is my first thought of a probable cause, that we are pointing wrong or in the wrong format.

If you are completely sure that is not the case and I'm assuming you attempted different formats and double check.

I have a few other ideas of things that you can checked out in order to discard potential causes.

1. Are you running in a different port than 8081?
2. What is your cloud sdk components version? Have you [updated them](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/components#updating_components) lately?

Have you attempted to pass manually the project ID in the curl?

Also, I'm understanding that you are importing data into the datastore emulator and everything is done locally.

Let me know.

**EDIT2**:

Hey Nelumbo, the only different things that I can think of that might be affecting you or for you to try is that I'm seeing that the configured port for the installation is 8432 and the one for the import is 8081 as you can see in the [following docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator#manually-set-environment-vars). When you checked the environment variables was it 8432 or 8081?

Another thing that I would suggest is attempting to do this in the Cloud Shell to make sure it works and if it does raise a public issue tracker with the GCP team as it might be an issue with the Windows version.

And at least try to update the SDK version to the latest one maybe it's related to that. But yeah, as the initial question of how to add a PROJECT ID to the emulator is solved, making a new one in order to also bring more visibility to it might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Stefan G. I quite can't believe I missed that. Sadly though it doesn't turn out that it was the problem. Checking the environment variables they are actually set correctly (I had done that step but not really checked it). 

Checking the running datastore emulation I see the following when I try to upload data: `[DATETIME] EM io.gapi.emulators.netty.NotFoundHandler handleRequest` \ `INFO: Unknown request URI: /v1/projects/[MYPROJECT]:import`. 
I know that on the google cloud site there is a space between ":" and "import", but that gives me a curl error.

Comment: Have a look at my edit and let me know. I'm pretty sure that this is an issue with the request URI and how we are pointing it. Cheers.

Comment: 1. Yes, it is running on port 8081. 
2. Cloud SDK version is 274 (datastore emulator version 2.1.0). 

I pass the project ID manually in the curl (i.e. replacing [PROJECT_ID] with my_project_id). 

Yes, everything is done locally (on Windows 10). 

Regarding the error that an entity does not exist: First time I run the datastore emulator and I haven't entered any entity manually either so the entire datastore should be empty. 

I downloaded the files manually (as exported file names from datastore are invalid in Windows) and setup the directories to reflect the setup of the export.

Comment: As the actual question has been answered. Should I just mark your answer as the answer and ask a new question specific for import data to local datastores?

Comment: Have a look at my latest edit Nelumbo. Hope it helps you out.